# Transitioning between development and production stages with AWS Step Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have an AWS Step Function that is large enough for me to start worrying about me missing errors updating and deploying.

I have created a duplicate Step Function "dev" and have been copying over my updated JSON from "dev" into my "prod" Step Function. There are lots of Lambda ARNs to update and permissions in both Step Function's IAM Role. I was wondering if there was a better/automatic way of updating the "prod" environment other than pasting my "dev" JSON and then updating all of the Lambda references manually?

Comment: How are you building your resources?  In the AWS console? CloudFormation?

Comment: Just in the AWS console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using words like "dev" and "prod" is a sign that you have outgrown the console.

AWS offers several [infrastructure-as-code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/introduction-devops-aws/infrastructure-as-code.html) approaches to deploy the same resources to multiple environments.  AWS [recommends](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/wellarchitected/2022-03-31/framework/ops_dev_integ_multi_env.html) a multi-environment setup, with a separate account per environment.

For low barriers of entry, consider the [Serverless Application Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html) (AWS SAM) and the [Cloud Development Kit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/home.html) (AWS CDK), which both support low-complexity CI/CD.  There are plenty of 3rd party IaaC solutions as well.

Comment: That's a great help. Thanks for the pointer!